# how to cleartimeout in node.js

Tags: node.js, settimeout, socket.io

Hi We are developing application in node.js , socket.io ,  and redis.

we have this procedure :

```
exports.processRequest = function (request,result) {
     var self = this;
     var timerknock;
     switch(request._command) {
    case 'some command': // user login with username 
            // some statement 
            timerknock=setTimeout(function() {
                //some  statemetn
            },20*1000);
        case 'other command ':
            // some statement    
            clearTimeout(timerknock);
      }
};
```

but when it cancel the timer it is not getting canceled when other command is executed , what should i do to cancel the timer ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you don't have `break` statements, which is going to cause problems (when you try and clear the timer it will make a new timer and clear it, but the old one will still run). Maybe that's a typo.

Your main problem is you're storing the timer "reference" in a local variable. That needs to be either enclosed or global, otherwise when you execute the function to clear the variable, `timerknock` has lost its value and will try and `clearTimeout(undefined)` which is of course, useless. I suggest a simple closure:

```
exports.processRequest = (function(){
   var timerknock;
   return function (request,result) {
      var self = this;
      switch(request._command) {
      case 'some command': // user login with username 
         // some statement 
         timerknock=setTimeout(function() {
            //some  statemetn
         },20*1000);
      case 'other command ':
         // some statement    
         clearTimeout(timerknock);
      }
   };
})();
```

Be aware that this too is a very simplistic approach, and if you set a timer before the current one has finished executing then you lose the reference to that timer. This might not be a problem for you, although you might try to implement this a little differently, with an object/array of timer references.