# Clearing timeouts for one item in array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, settimeout

Say I have an messaging service that schedules messages to friends,

And a user uploads their friends, along with **when** they want to send them

But say 10000 milliseconds later after scheduling, the uploader wants to take bob out of the (for) loop. How do I take bob out, without canceling scheduler. Or is there a better way to do this? (Its on a node server)

```
var friends = [‘John’, ‘bob’, ‘billy’, ‘dan’];

for (i in friends) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        sendMessage(friend[i])
    },3000000)
}
```

I feel like there is a much better way to do this but have not found anything

Thanks, new to js and appreciate the help!

Comment: NB: I think you'll have an issue with the curly quotes.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` returns an object. Store that somewhere, and then call `clearTimeout` with that object tif you want to do so, as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394645/1384352

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your code, all the timeouts will expire at the same time.

Instead you could only initiate the next timeout when the current one finishes. In the following demo 'Billy' is removed while the messages are being sent with an interval of 1 second. And indeed, Billy gets no message:

```js
var friends = ['John', 'Bob', 'Billy', 'Dan'];

(function loop(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (i >= friends.length) return; // all done        
        sendMessage(friends[i]);
        loop(i+1); // next
    }, 1000);
})(0); // call the function with index 0

function sendMessage(friend) { // mock
    console.log('send message to ' + friend);
}

// now remove 'Billy' after 2.5 second
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('remove ' + friends[2]);
    friends.splice(2, 1);
}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be that you add flag if user should be removed from the recipients and if flag is on you skip sending to that person. Then later on clean marked users when you can. e.g.

```
if (!friends[i].isRemoved) {
    setTimout.....
}
```

Other option would be that you define individual timers for each friend and then you can cancel who ever you want.